# php script for emailing variables with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have already posted on the ajax section on this very board and was advised to ask some php gurus for help.

The main problem I have is that I cannot manage the variables which are set in a contact form are successfully emailed to me. So there must be an error in the php file itself, although it is just a very simple testfile.

The important part of my JS looks like this:

```
$("#submitQuote").live('click',function(){
var shirt_style = "shirt_style="+$(".dropdown[title=shirt_style] .dropdownValue").text();
      var shirt_type = "&shirt_type="+$(".dropdown[title=shirt_type] .dropdownValue").text();
      var cuffs = "&cuffs="+$(".dropdown[title=cuffs] .dropdownValue").text();
      var chestpoket = "&chestpoket="+$(".dropdown[title=chestpoket] .dropdownValue").text();
      var collar = "&collar="+$(".dropdown[title=collar] .dropdownValue").text();
      var collar_buttons = "&collar_buttons="+$(".dropdown[title=collar_buttons] .dropdownValue").text();
      var fastening = "&fastening="+$(".dropdown[title=fastening] .dropdownValue").text();
      var cut = "&cut="+escape($(".dropdown[title=cut] .dropdownValue").text());

    var Name = "&Name="+escape($("input[name=Name]").val());
      var Email = "&Email="+escape($("input[name=Email]").val());
      var Phonenumber = "&Phonenumber="+escape($("input[name=Phonenumber]").val());
      var Address = "&Address="+escape($("input[name=Address]").val());
      var Zipcode = "&Zipcode="+escape($("input[name=Zipcode]").val());
      var City_country = "&City_country="+escape($("input[name=City_country]").val());
      var Copy = "&Copy="+$(".checkbox[title=Copy]").hasClass("checkboxChecked");

     var form_values1 = shirt_style+shirt_type+cuffs+chestpoket+collar+collar_buttons+fastening+cut;
      var form_values2 = form_values1+Name+Email+Phonenumber+Address+Zipcode+City_country+Copy;


      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://www. .com/ajax/quote.php",
       data: form_values2,

       success: function() {

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:290},1000);
        $("#quoteStepContainer").html('');
        $("#quoteStepContainer").html('<img src="http://www. ...com/img/sent.jpg" width="625" height="160" alt="Thanks" id="thanksImage" />');
        $("#thanksImage").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#quoteStepContainer").delay(1000).animate({"height": "190px"},1500);

       }
      }); 

      return false;


     });
```

the importnatn part of the html looks like this:

```
<form name="quoteForm" method="post" action="#">
  <div id="quoteStep1" class="quoteStep">

    <label>Shirt style</label>
    <div class="dropdown" title="shirt_style"></div>

    <label>Shirt type</label>
    <div class="dropdown" title="shirt_type"></div>

    <label>Collar</label>
    <div class="dropdown" title="collar"></div>

    <label>Collar Buttons</label>
    <div class="dropdown" title="collar_buttons"></div>

    <label>Cuffs</label>
    <div class="dropdown" title="cuffs"></div>

    <label>Chestpoket</label>
    <div class="dropdown" title="chestpoket"></div>

    <label>Fastening</label>
    <div class="dropdown" title="fastening"></div>

    <label>Cut</label>
    <div class="dropdown" title="cut"></div>


   <a href="#" title="To Step 2" class="nextStep"></a>

  </div>



  <div id="quoteStep2" class="quoteStep">

   <p class="stepText">Phew, the last step!</p>

    <label>Your name</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" class="required" />

    <label>E-mail</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email" />

    <label>Phone number</label>
    <input type="text" name="Phonenumber" />

    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="Address" />

    <label>Zip-code</label>
    <input type="text" name="Zipcode" />

    <label>City &amp; Country</label>
    <input type="text" name="City_country" />

    <label>Want a copy of the form?</label>
    <div class="checkbox" title="Copy"></div>


   <a href="#" title="To Step 1" class="prevStep"></a>
   <a href="#" title="Submit your inquiry" id="submitQuote"></a>

  </div>

  </form>
```

the input controls are defined over another js:

```
jQuery.fn.dropmenu = function (options,width) {
    var title = jQuery(this).attr('title');
    jQuery(this).css('width',width);
    jQuery(this).append('<div class="dropdownValue" title="'+title+'">'+options[0]+'</div>');
    jQuery(this).append('<ul class="dropdownList" title="'+title+'">');
    for(i=0; i<options.length; i++) { 
        jQuery(this).parent().find('.dropdownList[title='+title+']').append('<li>'+options[i]+'</li>');
    }

    jQuery(this).parent().find('.dropdownList').hide();
    jQuery(this).parent().find('.dropdownList').css('width',width);
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdownList li:first').addClass('first');
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdownList li:last').addClass('last');
    jQuery('.dropdownValue').toggle(function(){
        jQuery(this).parent().find('.dropdownList[title='+title+']').animate({"height": "toggle", "opacity": "toggle"}, 200);
        jQuery(this).addClass("dropdownValueClicked");
        jQuery('.dropdownList').not('.dropdownList[title='+title+']').hide();
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().find('.dropdownList[title='+title+']').animate({"height": "toggle", "opacity": "toggle"}, 200);
        jQuery(this).removeClass("dropdownValueClicked");
        jQuery('.dropdownList').not('.dropdownList[title='+title+']').hide();
    });

    jQuery('.dropdownList li').live('mouseenter',function() {
        jQuery(this).stop().addClass("hover");
    }).live('mouseleave', function() {
        jQuery(this).stop().removeClass("hover");
    });

    jQuery('.dropdownList[title='+title+'] li').live('mousedown',function(){
        jQuery('.dropdownValue').removeClass("dropdownValueClicked");
        var value = jQuery(this).html();
        jQuery(this).parent().animate({"height": "toggle", "opacity": "toggle"}, 200);
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.dropdownValue[title='+title+']').html(value);
    });
}
```

and the test php that doesnt work looks like this:

```
<?php
 $mail = $_POST['Email'];
 $name = $_POST['Name'];


 $to = "email@mydomain.com";
 $message =" You received  a mail from ".$mail;
 $message .=" His name is : ".$name;


 if(mail($to,$mail,$message)){
 echo "mail successful send";
} 
else{ 
 echo "there's some errors to send the mail, verify your server options";
}
?>
```

Thank you very much for all your time and effort.

Aaron

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the problem exactly? What are you being E-Mailed? Where does `form_values4` come from and what does it contain?

Comment: Pradon me Ive corrected the mistake. It must have been form_values2. The problem is that I cannot get the php script to email me the variables from the form. i only receive $message nothing more.

Comment: Maybe I got that wrong....do you literally receive "$message"???

Comment: No actually I receive: "You received  a mail from : His name is :" nothing more. Even when I process them as you explained it below. I have not faced that error before. Its strange.

Comment: Is the PHP script sat on the same server as the JS file?

Comment: Yes, they are all on the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im back now and have checked everything.
It seems a bit trickier than expected.

Actually it seems that I only receive valid emails, which means emails which include the variables from the form when I use Safari.
On browsers like FF and IE I only receive the message without the variables.

So on Safari I get the email:

> You received  a mail from testmail@test.com
>   His name is : testname Shirt style: Short

on FF and IE I receive, with the same settings the message

> You received  a mail from  His name
>   is :  Shirt style:

Additionally I receive the error in IE

> Access denied
>
> Row: 127 Sign: 287 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://www. .com/js/jquery.min.js

I do not receive an error message when viewing in FF with firebug.

Comment: If the behaviour depends on the browser it is probably NOT a php problem ;)

Comment: correct. I was a bit confusing at first because I was sure the simple php code has to work. But now I dont know how to continue. Why are the variables not passed over to the php form in IE or FF but only in safari? and what can I do to fix this issue? thank you oliver.

Comment: Its strange, Ive noticed that it depends whether I enter the emailform with or without the www. If I enter without the www. the emailform is not correctly displayed. If I enter with the www prefix everything works fine. I guess I have to configure the htaccess then

Comment: I have an idea in the javascrip try entering a relative adress in the javascript (url: "/ajax/quote.php" this MIGHT do the trick. Browsers limit AJAX calls to other domains, so maybe ie is having problems with calling www.bla.com when you are actually on bla.com. But thats just a wild gues :)

Comment: Ok I will try that Oliver! Meanwhile I have configured the htaccess for a permanent www redirect. Now FF and Safari are able to handle the form. Lets see if we have luck with your idea for IE. Thank you again for your time

Comment: I tried again with the changed htaccess file and saw that now every browser can handle the script. So the solution for this problem was the htaccess configuration. the domain must be redirected to www (permanent) in order to have the JS work properly for you. I thank you again and everyone in here. you are great guys.

Answer (score 1):

The content of your form is never proccessed in your php script.
You have to wirte the values that where send to your script into thhe $message variable.
Example

```
<?php
 $mail = $_POST['Email'];
 $name = $_POST['Name'];


 $to = "email@mydomain.com";
 $message =" You received  a mail from ".$mail;
 $message .=" His name is : ".$name."\n";
//add content to your mail!!!
 $message .= "Shirt style: {$_POST['shirt_style']}";

 if(mail($to,$mail,$message)){
 echo "mail successful send";
} 
else{ 
 echo "there's some errors to send the mail, verify your server options";
}
?>
```

Comment: Dear Oliver, that returns nothing more that the actual text, but no variables at all..Im desperate :(

Comment: Wait! now its finally working! I have to go now, but I will test it again today evening and inform you all about it! Thank you so much for all your effort, you are great!

Comment: I've added an answer for visibility as a comment. It does only work in Safari and no other browsers.